# How to set Vertical alignment to text in textbox control in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align the text in the middle to my textbox control in winforms.I also increased the height of the textbox by setting the  multiline property to true. But when editing the text, the text goes to the top-left position. I want it to be in the same position,even on edit mode and normal mode.
I want to achieve it like
[Excel-Normal mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6la5.png) and [Excel-EditMode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzBJE.png).Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're thinking of is a RichTextBox.
I forget if it supports vertical alignment, though I'm sure there is a work around.